# How to get from Copenhagen airport to Tivoli

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, copenhagen

What is my fastest option to get from Copenhagen airport to Tivoli by public transport on a weekday?

Answer (score 6):

This is actually really easy - I've been to Tivoli twice, and it's conveniently right next to the central train station.

As [Wikitravel says](http://wikitravel.org/en/Copenhagen#Get_in):

> It takes twelve minutes by train to get from Kastrup to the central
>   station (Hovedbanegården) in the city centre. You need a ticket for
>   three zones which can be purchased from one of the automated vending
>   machines or the ticket counter located inside the atrium and costs 36
>   Kr for a single journey. The Copenhagen Metro also connects
>   Kastrup with central Copenhagen, with trains leaving every four
>   minutes during the day and every fifteen minutes at night, taking
>   fourteen minutes to the city center (for the same ticket and price of
>   36.00 Kr).

And then from the Hovedbanegården station, follow the signs across the street to Tivoli. Enjoy it!